# jQuery UI - Applying Resizable() animation to block element without mouse intervention

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to apply animate effect of `resizable()` to html block elements when the web browser window is re-sized. This is to add some cool motion effect on top of responsive fluid design.

As far as I can tell from looking at [jQuery UI API](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-alsoResize), it only seems to work with mouse interaction.

How do I make it trigger `resizable()` everytime browser window gets re-sized?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can wrap and trigger the resize() function

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
     $(".selector").trigger("resize");
 });
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523522/how-to-trigger-jquery-resizable-resize-programmatically)