# jQuery how to get the value of each stop event in resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to get the value for each stop event values in resizable method

```
function calc(){
  $(function() {
    $(".txt").resizable({
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        var w = ui.size.width;
        var h = ui.size.height;
        var Font_size=parseInt($(".txt").css("font-size"));
      }
    });
  });
}

console.log(Font_size); //when I try this - variable undefined
```

When ever I try to print the value of **Font_size** show undefined

How I can get this values any ideas?

Comment: Your log is called before the event even occurs. Also `Font_size` variable is only scoped inside the `stop` callback.

Comment: i want to use the values out side of funtion

Comment: To do what specifically?

Comment: i have text on resizable element

Comment: when resizable stops it will automatically  resized it's fine but

Comment: Ok...but that doesn't explain very much. A [mcve] along with proper explanation of what you are trying to accomplish would help. We can't really guess at what you are trying to do

Comment: simply i want to use this  variable in out side of the funtion

Comment: That is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: have you understood my problem

Comment: No ... because you haven't explained what the higher level problem you want to solve is. Read that XY problem link thoroughly

Comment: that is not higher level problem

Comment: Well unless you tell us more specifically what you are trying to do nobody can help

Comment: i will explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

Resize is an event and the `stop` is an event handler for that stop event.  You can access that stop event, including calling a function inside the event handler - which I infer from your question.  You only put in place that event handler when that `calc` function is called with the document ready event handler(which event has already fired) I place the event handler outside that function call.   Rather than setting some static global that is logged, here I show how to call a function when it is triggered and log it there.

EDIT: Added second example to show how to set global on startup with some helpers.

```js
function calc(fontSize) {
  console.log("calc:",fontSize);
}
function calc2(event, ui) {
  let fontSize2 = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"), 10);
  console.log('calc2:', fontSize2);
  console.log('calc2 More:', ui.size.width, ui.size.height);
}

$(function() {
  $(".txt").resizable({
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      let w = ui.size.width;
      let h = ui.size.height;
      let Font_size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"), 10);
      calc(Font_size);
    }
  });
  $(".txt").on("resizestop", calc2);
});
```

```css
.txt {
  border: solid 2px lime;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2em;
}

.bigger-size {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.tiny-size {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="txt normal-size">happy slappy resizable text </div>
<div class="txt bigger-size">happy slappy resizable text </div>
<div class="txt tiny-size"><span>Howdy</span> happy slappy resizable text </div>
```

Further, to demonstrate how to actually get things working with your global variable (which is `undefined` because it was set after your console.log)

```js
// borrow some code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2523758/125981
$.widget("ui.resizable", $.ui.resizable, {
  resizeTo: function(newSize) {
    var start = new $.Event("mousedown", {
      pageX: 0,
      pageY: 0
    });
    this._mouseStart(start);
    this.axis = 'se';
    var end = new $.Event("mouseup", {
      pageX: newSize.width - this.originalSize.width,
      pageY: newSize.height - this.originalSize.height
    });
    this._mouseDrag(end);
    this._mouseStop(end);
  }
});

var calc = function calc(event, ui) {
  console.log('calc', "ui:", ui ? ui.size : undefined);
  let w = ui.size.width;
  let h = ui.size.height;
  console.log("calc Font_size:", window.Font_size);
}

function calc2(event, ui) {
  console.log('calc2', ui.size);
}

$(function() {
  // bind an event we can use to add resizable event
  $(".resizable-things")
    .find('.txt')
    .on('bind-resizable', function(event, options, others) {
      $(this).resizable(options);
    });

  // trigger to bind tiny-size
  $('.txt.tiny-size').trigger('bind-resizable', {
    grid: [20, 10],
    stop: calc2
  });

  // trigger to bind others
  $('.resizable-things')
    .find('.txt')
    .not('.txt.tiny-size')
    .not(".txt.bigger-size")
    .trigger('bind-resizable', {
      stop: calc
    });

  $('#testresize').one('click', function(event) {
    let b = $(".txt.bigger-size");
    b.trigger('bind-resizable', {
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        // just to show it binds
        console.log('stop w', ui.size.width);
        console.log($(this).css('font-size'));
        // create our bad idea global variable
         window.Font_size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"), 10);
        calc.call(this, event, ui);
      },
      alsoResize: ".txt-mirror",
    });

    let m = $('.txt-mirror');
    b.css("font-size", "1.65em");
    b.resizable("resizeTo", {
      // 190% height of the mirror which changes the mirror height on trigger resizeTo
      height: (m.height() / 100) * 190,
      width: (m.width()/100) * 55//55 percent width
    });
    $(this).hide();//hide button
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-resizable {
  border: solid 2px lime;
}

.bigger-size {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 1px cyan dashed;
  margin: 1em;
}

.tiny-size {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.txt-mirror,
.txt-mirror .show {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="txt txt-mirror">I mirror resize text<span class="show">?</span> </div>
<div class="container resizable-things">
  <div class="txt normal-size">happy slappy resizable text I am other </div>
  <div class="txt bigger-size">happy slappy resizable text </div>
  <div class="txt tiny-size"><span>Howdy</span> happy slappy resizable text </div>
</div>
<button id="testresize" type='button'>test event</button>
```

Comment: I added a second function example to show how to add another handler/alternative way to add one.

Comment: superb second one also working thank you

how i can use in other funtions

Comment: "how i can use in other funtions" that depends on your needs, likely store that value somewhere however, it will change every time you resize so perhaps call those other functions when this event fires (or trigger a custom event with the value as a parameter)

Comment: Tried what exactly?  This "stop" is an event, here is some information on events https://api.jquery.com/category/events/  and for those specific to the jQuery UI resizable the events are listed here: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: I added a second example to show how to trigger the resize on initial startup and set a global variable.

Comment: Did this resolve your issue, if not please update your question with a clear, concise description of what you wish to accomplish as a result of this and what the exact challenge is that you face. 

 If this (or any other answer) did answer your question please mark it as such by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calc(){
$(function() {
    $(".txt").resizable({
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            var w = ui.size.width;
            var h = ui.size.height;
            var Font_size=parseInt($(".txt").css("font-size"));
            console.log(Font_size);
        }});
});
}
```

OR

```
var Font_size = 0;
function calc(){
$(function() {
    $(".txt").resizable({
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            var w = ui.size.width;
            var h = ui.size.height;
            Font_size=parseInt($(".txt").css("font-size"));

        }});
});
}
console.log(Font_size);
```

Comment: can i return the value to use out of method

Comment: Provide an explanation . Code only answers are not very valuable without explanation

Comment: i tried second choice of code but it's shows only 0

not updating resizable stop event