# Button onClick in not working with this JS or trigger jquery Resizable Font-size programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is a resizable UI plugin JS that is working fine with **mouse click & drag**.
It's changing it's `font-size` with mouse. Meaning, when I change the width or height of my `div` with `id="chartdiv"` from **mouse corner** then it is changing the `font-size` correctly. However, when I change the width or height of my `div` with `id="chartdiv"` from **button onClick**, then it's not working.
I want to use this `font-size` resizable feature from Button.

For this query I already visited to this answer: [How to trigger jquery Resizable resize programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523522/how-to-trigger-jquery-resizable-resize-programmatically) but there is not `font-size` function

What mistake am I making here?

***Below is my code:***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .resize{
    font-size: 2.8vh;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: black;
    background: yellow;
    cursor: move;
    width: 300px;
    height: 130px
}

 .resize:focus {
   width: 500px;  }

    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <button type="button" onClick = "document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.width = '600px';">Click Me!</button>
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="resize" id="chartdiv">Some name that is very long</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.resize').resizable( {
minWidth: 210,
minHeight: 120,
resize: function( event, ui ) {
        // handle fontsize here
        var size = ui.size;
        // something like this change the values according to your requirements
        $( this ).css( 'font-size', ( size.width * size.height ) / 2800 + 'px' ); 
    }
} );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you resize div it trigger resize event with function that you have written, but when you click on button it explicitly set style width not resize event.to do this you have to write separate function for button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following creates a simple jQuery plugin function `fontResize()` that can be used in both instances

```js
$.fn.fontResize = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    const $el = $(this);
    $el.css('font-size', ($el.width() * $el.height()) / 2800 + 'px');
  });
}

$('button.do-resize').click(function(){
   $('#chartdiv').width(600).fontResize()// use plugin function
})


$('.resize').resizable({
  minWidth: 210,
  minHeight: 120,
  resize: function(event, ui) {   
    $(this).fontResize();// use plugin function
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .resize {
      font-size: 2.8vh;
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: black;
      background: yellow;
      cursor: move;
      width: 300px;
      height: 130px
    }
    
    .resize:focus {
      width: 500px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button class="do-resize"  type="button" >Click Me!</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <div class="resize" id="chartdiv">Some name that is very long</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello @charlietfl plz tell me can i make this resize with smooth animation ? and how ?

Comment: Check out jQuery `animate()` https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: can you help me to add this plzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" onClick = "ResizeWithButton();">Click Me!</button>

function ResizeWithButton(){
     var x = document.getElementById('chartdiv');
     x.style.width = '600px';
     var rect = x.getBoundingClientRect();
     x.style.fontSize = `${(rect.width * rect.height)/2800}px`;
}
```